# Add a string after each item in Wordpress menu

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to add a special character to display a » alongside each menu item in Wordpress.

So for example

About us »
Contact us »
And so on...

Here's my code

```
      <li><?php echo $children; echo '»'; ?></li>
```

I expected this would do the job, but it just puts the » below the list.

Here's the full code

```
      <?php
      if($post->post_parent) {
      $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0");
      $titlenamer = get_the_title($post->post_parent);
      }

      else {
      $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0");
      $titlenamer = get_the_title($post->ID);
      }
      if ($children) { ?>

      <h2 class="left_title">
        <?php echo $titlenamer ?>
      </h2>
      <ul class="left_body">

        <li><?php echo $children; echo '»'; ?></li>

      </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If $children were a variable you would concatenate the string using `.`.
So basically you'd just do `echo $children.'»';`

However, $children could be an array, or at least a list of items for the menu, so it would require concatenating each item in the list.

```
<li>
  <?php 
    foreach ($children as $child){
      $child = $child.'»'; 
  ?>
</li>
```

This would do the trick I think, but I'm not sure the structure of $children.

Side note:  I would use `&#187;` in place of ».

Comment: hmm, thank you but not having much luck with this so far. Do you perhaps have a suggestion on where I can look to see what to put in place of child

Comment: Ah you know what, I don't think I really payed enough attention to the code.  So it looks like $children is just a long string with all of your menu items as links.  So could you please do `var_dump($children);`?

Comment: This is going to be tricky without seeing the function in `wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0");`.  Maybe someone else can see what's going on there.  Your $children string is all of the different links rolled into one string, so it's really not a good idea to do a replace on `' '` with `' &#187; '` on that string.  We need to find where the spaces are appended in the function and change those.